# Load image from a stored png

Tags: iphone

How does one load or fetch an image that was saved to disk?

I wrote the image to the documents filepath using NSData and a PNG representation. How does one get this image back? UIImage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

As ever, see the [UIImage documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) at Apple. It is your friend.

Comment: If you're using OpenGL, [GLKTextureLoader](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKTextureLoader_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) may be the way to go